# Regex on File Names

Tags: php, regex

I have a function called `getContents()`, Which accepts a regex for the file names it finds.

I scan the `js` folder for javascript files, with the following two regex patterns:

```
$js['head'] = "/(\.head\.js\.php)|(\.head\.js)|(\.h.js)/";
$js['foot'] = "/(\.foot\.js\.php)|(\.foot\.js)|(\.f.js)|(\.js)^(\.head\.js)/";
```

I have a naming system whereby if you determine where the javascript file gets loaded, in the `<head>` tag or footer of the HTML page.  All files are generally considered to be loaded at the bottom of the page, unless you specify (`.head.js` for example).

Up until a few days a go I noticed that the `js['foot']` array was also including `.head.js` as well, causing the files to be loaded twice.  So I added in the `^(\.head\.js)` and it worked! it stopped the .head.js files being added into the footer array.  I was quite pleased with myself, because I suck at regex.  However it seems now that standard `.js` files (any normal `.js` files) arnt being loaded into the `$js['foot']` array now.  Why is this? If I remove the `^(\.head\.js)` part it loads them.

To be clear, I want the `$js['foot']` array to load files ending with:

```
.foot.js.php
.foot.js
.f.js
.js
```

And IGNORE all:

```
.head.js.php
.head.js
.h.js
```

Can someone correct my regex above to do this? I thought the `^` operator was `NOT` but i was wrong!

Comment: I tend to split my files in separate folder instead of relying on a "barely" documented naming convention. Perhaps you could split your js files in two folders instead, then say bye bye to the regexes?

Comment: I think I’d rather just do this via two separate `glob` calls … / On a side note, why `foot` _and_ `f`, resp. `head` _and_ `h` – do these have any special meaning/different purpose as well?

Comment: @CBroe just to give options for naming, instead of writing out `.head.js` everytime, `.h.js` is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^(\.head\.js)` in the middle of string makes it an invalid because `^` is considered anchor that matches line start.

You actually need a *negative lookbehind assertion* to stop matching `head.js` in footer regex:

```
$js['head'] = '/\.head\.js(?:\.php)?|\.h.js/';
$js['foot'] = '/\.foot\.js(?:\.php)?|(?<!head|h)\.js/';
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wU1zA8/4)

Comment: This example won't load `.js` will it? Could you write the regex to match the example above?

Comment: [It is matching any `.js` other than `head.js`, as per this demo](https://regex101.com/r/wU1zA8/4) How are you using it?

Comment: It seems to work!  Thank you - I havent been to regex101 before.  I'll learn lots on there.  Thanks.